# Run time error 91(object variable or With block variable not set) within a loop, but code working outside it

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to delete all rows containing #REF text. But I get error in the object.

I have tried to pull out the code from the loop and worked. How can this happen? Is it the nested loop?

1)Not working code

```
Sub FindDeleteLoop()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim objcell As Range
Dim delrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

For Each sh1 In wb1.Worksheets
    With sh1

        RowCount = sh1.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=sh1.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

        For i = 1 To RowCount
            On Error GoTo nextcom
            Set objcell = sh1.Cells.Find(What:="*#REF*", After:=sh1.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

            objcell.EntireRow.Delete

            Next i

            nextcom:
        End With


    Next
End Sub
```

Then I attempted the same outside the second loop and I got a
2) Working Code by replacing

```
For Each sh1 In wb1.Worksheets
```

with

```
Set sh1 = wb1.ActiveSheet
```

I just don't get the rationale for it.

Comment: Consider what happens when you get to a sheet where there are no cells with **#REF** cells. Now you are trying to delete rows in a range which has no cells.. let alone rows

Comment: What line do you receive this error?

Comment: @Zac isn't On Error GoTo nextcom handling this?

Comment: @ Dean it is 
RowCount = sh1.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=sh1.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

Comment: That could mean that you are not finding `*` when you are trying to get the `.Row` value. Try `Debug.Print sh1.Name` and check that you can in fact, find that on that sheet.

Comment: You're also missing `RowCount` in your declarations...

Comment: There are better ways to find the last row of a worksheet.  Assume that column 1 represents the length of the data, then `RowCount = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` will work.  More efficient than searching every cell.

Comment: @Dean, I found out with your test that it stops on empty pages. I used On Error GoTo Next, but it stops at the first empty page even with that.

Comment: That's `Range.Find("*", ...)` yielding `Nothing` given an empty sheet. See answer below, that's covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indentation is extremely misleading. Let's [fix it](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) first:

```
For Each sh1 In wb1.Worksheets
    With sh1

        RowCount = sh1.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=sh1.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

        For i = 1 To RowCount
            On Error GoTo nextcom
            Set objcell = sh1.Cells.Find(What:="*#REF*", After:=sh1.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

            objcell.EntireRow.Delete

        Next i

nextcom: 
    End With
Next
```

The problem is that the error state is never cleared, so whenever `Range.Find` returns `Nothing`, the next instruction is illegal:

```
objcell.EntireRow.Delete 'objcell is Nothing ~> error 91
```

So the inner loop keeps going *while VBA is still in an error state*, and the next iteration's `On Error` statement is thus ignored - and when the next `objcell.EntireRow` throws error 91, execution abruptly stops.

The solution is to remove the `On Error` statements, and use normal flow control - that is, only invoke a member on `objcell` when you **know** that it's holding a valid object reference:

```
If Not objcell Is Nothing Then objcell.EntireRow.Delete
```

---

The code has other issues, too. `Range.Find` is searching the entire worksheet: there is no need to iterate every single row.

> ```
> RowCount = sh1.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=sh1.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
> ```

This will fail with error 91 if `sh1` is an empty worksheet, because the `Row` member call will go against `Nothing`. Consider this much safer approach:

```
RowCount = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Regardless, we don't really care what the row count is - we can just keep searching the sheet until there are no more results:

```
Do
    Set objcell = sh1.Cells.Find(...)
    If Not objcell Is Nothing Then objcell.EntireRow.Delete
Loop While Not objcell Is Nothing
```

But back at the faulty error handling.

> [*isn't On Error GoTo nextcom handling this?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729141/run-time-error-91object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set-within-a-loop#comment101898996_57729141)

As briefly mentioned above, the answer is "yes", with a caveat: if the error isn't actually *handled*, then VBA doesn't know it's back on the "happy path", and merrily keeps iterating *while still in an error state*.

So the problem is that your error execution path is intertwined with the normal execution path: whenever you setup an error handler subroutine, you need to make sure the error-handling subroutine only ever runs in an error state, *and either actually handles the error state or exits the procedure*.

Adding `Err.Clear` between the `nextcom:` label and the `End With` that follows would clear the error state and the loop would work... but you would still have intertwined execution paths: as shown above, that's a sign that you're using error handling for flow control, and that's making the code harder to follow than it needs to be.

Here's the bad code, with execution paths de-tangled for illustrative purposes only (use the above `Do...While` loop instead!)

```
    For Each sh1 In wb1.Worksheets
        With sh1

            RowCount = sh1.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=sh1.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

            For i = 1 To RowCount
                On Error GoTo ErrHandler
                Set objcell = sh1.Cells.Find(What:="*#REF*", After:=sh1.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

                objcell.EntireRow.Delete

            Next i

        End With
nextcom: '<~ never jump back into a With...End With block
    Next

    Exit Sub '<~ "happy path" ends here
ErrHandler:  '<~ "error path" starts here
    Debug.Assert Err.Number = 91 'execution stops here if that isn't the case
    Resume nextcom '<~ 'Resume' clears the error state
```

Comment: Wow, +1 for such a wonderful answer! Amazing effort and hopefully OP takes away lots from this!

Comment: @Matieu Guindon Thank you for the lectio magistralis. Not only it solved my problem, but it gave me a great insight on loops and error handling